# How to plot Geoserver data (point data) as image on the map instead of vector plot?

Tags: vector, image, mapping, angular

Need the help to integrate it with angular 5 if possible.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please be focus what you ask ,also did you researched on your side ?